# use the case statement and set a different value for every each top 10 records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, case, window-functions

I have a table that returns a list of records with two-column:

```
SELECT Id, Duration from dbo.[VW_ActivityDuration] ORDER BY DURATION desc
```

I want to use the `case` statement and set a different value for every top 10 records, which is ordered by **DURATION** in descending.

Example:

```
set the value as 5 for the first 10 records 

and set the value as 4 for the next 10 records 

and set the value as 3 for the other next 10 records 

and set the value as 2 for the other next 10 records
```

similarly, I have to set the value of 1 for all after that

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [Id]
      ,[Name],

      CASE
        WHEN  ---  THEN '5'
        ELSE '1'
    END AS [Value]

  FROM [EngagementDb].[dbo].[VW_ActivityDuration]
  ORDER BY [DurationMinutes] desc
```

Any head-start, hints, or suggestions would be appreciated. I couldn't start writing a query to start with this problem.

Comment: The value is always the same, so I don't understand the question.

Comment: `CASE` **expression**; SQL Server does not support `Case` (`Switch`) statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `row_number()` and a `case` expression:

```
select id, DurationMinutes,
    case 
        when row_number() over(order by DurationMinutes desc) <= 10 then 5
        when row_number() over(order by DurationMinutes desc) <= 20 then 4
        when row_number() over(order by DurationMinutes desc) <= 30 then 3
        when row_number() over(order by DurationMinutes desc) <= 40 then 2
        else 1
    end as val
from [EngagementDb].[dbo].[VW_ActivityDuration]
order by DurationMinutes desc
```

We can shorten that a little with arithmetics:

```
select id, DurationMinutes,
    case when row_number() over(order by DurationMinutes desc) <= 40 
        then 5 - (row_number() over(order by DurationMinutes desc) - 1) / 10
        else 1
    end as val
from [EngagementDb].[dbo].[VW_ActivityDuration]
order by DurationMinutes desc
```